Deploy flask to the server
The mainstream solution for deploying flask on the server is to package it into an exe and execute it on the server or directly execute the py file.
What are the main popular deployment solutions now? What are the pros and cons of these options?？

There are many options to deploy flask applications. The most well-known are 1)Docker, 2)Platform as a Service(Paas) Providers like(Heroku, Google App Engine), 3)Traditional Virtual Private Servers(VPS) like Digital Ocean. The pros and the cons of these are various. 1)Docker provides a standard environment for deploying the applications and is easy to package flask applications with the dependencies and configurations, on the other hand the learning curve is steep if someone is not familiar and also requires additional setup comparing with other deployment methods. 2(Paas) Providers they have easy and fast deploy and they offer integrations with other services (databases, Logging) but they are limited on customizations and it may occur additional costs depending on the scale of the app(Bigger more expensive). 3 VPS they are more suitable for larger applications and they provide full control on the server environment but they require additional  manual setup and the user is responsible for the security , updates and backups.
